# macOS notifications on dual monitors: how can I specify which monitor?

Tags: macos, notifications, dual-screen

I would like to have macOS Notification Center notifications on my left monitor and not my right monitor. It's hard to see them when I'm looking at the left monitor (since they're all the way on the right side and they're rather large monitors).

Is there any way to keep the screens in this order, but have the notifications appear on the screen I want them to appear on?

Answer (score 244, accepted):

You should be able to do this by choosing the monitor on which the menu bar is active.

Try:

- System Settings -> Displays -> Arrangement

and drag the little white bar to the monitor where you want the notifications to show up.

In the picture below, the bar is being dragged from the left to the right window.

[image: Arrangement window with mouse]

Comment: Wow this isn't at all obvious.

Comment: This works, of course, but it also causes the (⌘-Tab) Application Switcher to move to that monitor. Is there a way to change the location of _only_ notifications?

Comment: I'm amazed by this post! It works like a charm!

Comment: Oddly, the cmd-tab selections appear only on the Macbook Pro's screen, while the notifications are on the primary screen (the one with the white bar)

Comment: I missed a meeting at work today because iCal was popping up on the laptop screen away to my right instead of my Thunderbolt dispaly.

Comment: @wrlee to switch where teh cmd-tab selections appear, on the display where you want them to appear, mouse over the dock on that display. That effectively switches where cmd-tab list shows up.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately this moves the menu bar, which I *don't* want to move. There really should be some way to move just the notifications.

Comment: @JohnQ thanks for the tip .. just to repeat the first comment: *"Wow this isn't at all obvious."* -- Apple style: lot of features, but unreasonably hidden... 

Comment: It's nearly 2020 and this is still not possible to configure in a convenient way :( or even to show it on both displays, it's super easy to miss some important stuff.

Comment: Works in Catalina. Another useful tip along these lines. To move the dock between monitors, move your mouse to the bottom of the screen on the monitor where you want your dock. You need to hold it to the bottom center for a couple seconds. I'd prefer to have the dock on both screens, but not sure it's possible.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue.This moves notifications and the dock and everything else. I want to have only *notifications* on a different monitor.

Comment: The top literally says, "To relocate the menu bar, drag it to a different display."  I never actually read that. LOL.

Comment: This might work if your screens are side by side but if one is above the other, the notifications remain on the top screen regardless of where the dock is.

Comment: There is no more white bar on Ventura (macOS 13), or at least with one laptop and one external monitor.

Comment: I'm running Sonoma where this seems to be different. If you go to System Settings -> Displays, you can click the monitor where you want to have the notifications appear. Then in the section below the monitors, you will see a setting called "Use As". Change the value in the drop-down to "Main display". Now the notifications will appear on that display. The desktops will switch monitors, so you may have to arrange your desktops back to the monitors you want them on. (I use two monitors and leave my laptop cover close.)

Answer (score 37):

In case you have mirrored displays and you have no notifications appearing on either screen, you might have fallen victim of the "DO NOT DISTURB - Enabled while mirrored" setting.

To change this setting, open the notification centre on the right, scroll up in the list to reveal the hidden settings panel, and toggle the DO NOT DISTURB switch.

[image: do not disturb]

On macOS Monterey, this setting has moved to System Preferences > Notifications:

[image: System Preferences Notifications - Allow Notifications]

On macOS Ventura, this is where you find it:

[image: macOS Ventura Notifications]

This setting also affects applications like `OBS Studio` when a `Display Capture` source is active.

Comment: WOW, why is this setting enabled by default?
This was the fix in my case

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reason is to prevent notifications from private conversations from popping up when people are presenting their screen for work! The Zoom video conferencing app also turns on DND by default when screen sharing.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had the same issue while using the software "Duet Display" that allows one to use an iPad as a second screen.

Answer (score -1):

The notification side-tray should appear on the screen which your cursor is currently positioned;  it need not be the screen with the active menu bar... I've found that it isn't always consistent, and sometimes appears on whichever screen it last appeared. I was able to sync it up to the expected behavior by opening and closing the tray from the menu bar icon rather than trackpad gesture.

Comment: This appears to be untrue in Catalina. Notifications appear always on the same screen, regardless of which one is in focus.